# Hazelcast failed to start in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, rbac

I have a HA Kubernetes cluster that initialized with custom certificates. I want to run Hazelcast on it, but there is an error in discovering Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API.
This is my deploy file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: hazelcast
  labels:
    app: hazelcast
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: hazelcast-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hazelcast
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hazelcast
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: nexuspullsecret
      containers:
      - name: hazelcast
        image: 192.168.161.187:9050/hazelcast-custom:4.0.2
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - name: hazelcast
          containerPort: 5701
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /hazelcast/health/node-state
            port: 5701
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /hazelcast/health/node-state
            port: 5701
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 1
        resources:
            requests:
              memory: "0"
              cpu: "0"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hazelcast-storage
          mountPath: /data/hazelcast
        env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Dhazelcast.rest.enabled=true -Dhazelcast.config=/data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml"
      volumes:
      - name: hazelcast-storage
        configMap:
          name: hazelcast-configuration

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hazelcast
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5701

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-cluster-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["endpoints", "pods", "nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-cluster-role-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: hazelcast-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io 
---

apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: hazelcast
  namespace: default
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hazelcast


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-configuration
data:
  hazelcast.xml: |-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
           http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-4.0.xsd">
      <network>
        <rest-api enabled="true"></rest-api>
        <join>
          <!-- deactivate normal discovery -->
          <multicast enabled="false"/>
          <tcp-ip enabled="false" />
          <!-- activate the Kubernetes plugin -->
          <kubernetes enabled="true">
            <service-name>hazelcast-service</service-name>
            <namespace>default</namespace>
            <kubernetes-api-retries>20</kubernetes-api-retries>
          </kubernetes>
        </join>
      </network>
      <user-code-deployment enabled="true">
        <class-cache-mode>ETERNAL</class-cache-mode>
        <provider-mode>LOCAL_AND_CACHED_CLASSES</provider-mode>
      </user-code-deployment>
      <reliable-topic name="ConfirmationTimeout">
        <read-batch-size>10</read-batch-size>
        <topic-overload-policy>DISCARD_OLDEST</topic-overload-policy>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
      </reliable-topic>
      <ringbuffer name="ConfirmationTimeout">
        <capacity>10000</capacity>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
      </ringbuffer>
      <scheduled-executor-service name="ConfirmationTimeout">
        <capacity>100</capacity>
        <capacity-policy>PER_NODE</capacity-policy>
        <pool-size>32</pool-size>
        <durability>3</durability>
        <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.spi.merge.PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
      </scheduled-executor-service>
      <cp-subsystem>
        <cp-member-count>3</cp-member-count>
        <group-size>3</group-size>
        <session-time-to-live-seconds>300</session-time-to-live-seconds>
        <session-heartbeat-interval-seconds>5</session-heartbeat-interval-seconds>
        <missing-cp-member-auto-removal-seconds>14400</missing-cp-member-auto-removal-seconds>
        <fail-on-indeterminate-operation-state>false</fail-on-indeterminate-operation-state>
        <raft-algorithm>
            <leader-election-timeout-in-millis>15000</leader-election-timeout-in-millis>
            <leader-heartbeat-period-in-millis>5000</leader-heartbeat-period-in-millis>
            <max-missed-leader-heartbeat-count>10</max-missed-leader-heartbeat-count>
            <append-request-max-entry-count>100</append-request-max-entry-count>
            <commit-index-advance-count-to-snapshot>10000</commit-index-advance-count-to-snapshot>
            <uncommitted-entry-count-to-reject-new-appends>100</uncommitted-entry-count-to-reject-new-appends>
            <append-request-backoff-timeout-in-millis>100</append-request-backoff-timeout-in-millis>
        </raft-algorithm>
        <locks>
            <fenced-lock>
                <name>TimeoutLock</name>
                <lock-acquire-limit>1</lock-acquire-limit>
            </fenced-lock>
        </locks>
      </cp-subsystem>
      <metrics enabled="true">
        <management-center>
            <retention-seconds>30</retention-seconds>
        </management-center>
        <jmx enabled="false"/>
        <collection-frequency-seconds>10</collection-frequency-seconds>
      </metrics>
    </hazelcast>
```

I have tested this deploy file on non-custom certificate ssl HA Kubernetes cluster and it works without any problems.

This is log files:

```
    ######################################## 
# JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.rest.enabled=true -Dhazelcast.config=/data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml 
# CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*:/opt/hazelcast/user-lib/* 
# CLASSPATH_DEFAULT=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*:/opt/hazelcast/user-lib/* 
# starting now.... 
######################################## 
+ exec java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dhazelcast.rest.enabled=true -Dhazelcast.config=/data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml com.hazelcast.core.server.HazelcastMemberStarter 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:36 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator 
INFO: Loading configuration '/data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml' from System property 'hazelcast.config' 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:37 AM com.hazelcast.internal.config.AbstractConfigLocator 
INFO: Using configuration file at /data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:40 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker 
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.2] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:40 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker 
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.2] Picked [10.42.128.11]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:40 AM com.hazelcast.system 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Hazelcast 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) starting at [10.42.128.11]:5701 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:40 AM com.hazelcast.system 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:42 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Backpressure is disabled 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:43 AM com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.integration.DiscoveryService 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Kubernetes Discovery properties: { service-dns: null, service-dns-timeout: 5, service-name: hazelcast-service, service-port: 0, service-label: null, service-label-value: true, namespace: default, pod-label: null, pod-label-value: null, resolve-not-ready-addresses: true, use-node-name-as-external-address: false, kubernetes-api-retries: 20, kubernetes-master: https://kubernetes.default.svc} 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:43 AM com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.integration.DiscoveryService 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Kubernetes Discovery activated with mode: KUBERNETES_API 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:43 AM com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:43 AM com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] CP Subsystem is enabled with 3 members. 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:44 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks) 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:44 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments. 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:45 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService 
INFO: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] [10.42.128.11]:5701 is STARTING 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:47 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [1] retrying in 1 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:49 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [2] retrying in 2 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:51 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [3] retrying in 3 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:08:54 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [4] retrying in 5 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:00 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [5] retrying in 7 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:07 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [6] retrying in 11 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:12 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) 
 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:14 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) 
 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:19 AM com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils 
WARNING: Couldn't discover Hazelcast members using Kubernetes API, [7] retrying in 17 seconds... 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:22 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) 
 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:24 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) 
 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:32 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80) 
 
Sep 08, 2020 7:09:34 AM com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpPostCommandProcessor 
WARNING: [10.42.128.11]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] An error occurred while handling request HttpCommand [HTTP_GET]{uri='/hazelcast/health/node-state'}AbstractTextCommand[HTTP_GET]{requestId=0} 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handleHealthcheck(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:137) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:79) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.rest.HttpGetCommandProcessor.handle(HttpGetCommandProcessor.java:47) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.ascii.TextCommandServiceImpl$CommandExecutor.run(TextCommandServiceImpl.java:396) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64) 
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

This is our custom dockerfile for Hazelcast that because we need some changes in it:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

# Versions of Hazelcast and Hazelcast plugins
ARG HZ_VERSION=4.0.2
ARG CACHE_API_VERSION=1.1.1
ARG JMX_PROMETHEUS_AGENT_VERSION=0.13.0
ARG BUCKET4J_VERSION=4.10.0

# Build constants
ARG HZ_HOME="/opt/hazelcast"

# JARs to download
# for lib directory:
ARG HAZELCAST_ALL_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/${HZ_VERSION}/hazelcast-all-${HZ_VERSION}.jar"
# for user-lib directory:
ARG JCACHE_API_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/cache/cache-api/${CACHE_API_VERSION}/cache-api-${CACHE_API_VERSION}.jar"
ARG PROMETHEUS_AGENT_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/${JMX_PROMETHEUS_AGENT_VERSION}/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-${JMX_PROMETHEUS_AGENT_VERSION}.jar"
ARG BUCKET4J_CORE_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j-core/${BUCKET4J_VERSION}/bucket4j-core-${BUCKET4J_VERSION}.jar"
ARG BUCKET4J_HAZELCAST_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j-hazelcast/${BUCKET4J_VERSION}/bucket4j-hazelcast-${BUCKET4J_VERSION}.jar"
ARG BUCKET4J_JCACHE_URL="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j-jcache/${BUCKET4J_VERSION}/bucket4j-jcache-${BUCKET4J_VERSION}.jar"

# Runtime constants / variables
ENV HZ_HOME="${HZ_HOME}" \
    CLASSPATH_DEFAULT="${HZ_HOME}/*:${HZ_HOME}/lib/*:${HZ_HOME}/user-lib/*" \
    JAVA_OPTS_DEFAULT="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${HZ_HOME}/logging.properties -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+UseParallelGC --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED" \
    PROMETHEUS_PORT="" \
    PROMETHEUS_CONFIG="${HZ_HOME}/jmx_agent_config.yaml" \
    LOGGING_LEVEL="" \
    CLASSPATH="" \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# Expose port
EXPOSE 5701

COPY *.sh *.yaml *.jar *.properties ${HZ_HOME}/
RUN echo "Updating Alpine system" \
    && apk upgrade --update-cache --available \
    && echo "Installing new APK packages" \
    && apk add openjdk11-jre bash curl procps nss 
RUN mkdir "${HZ_HOME}/user-lib"\
    && cd "${HZ_HOME}/user-lib" \
    && for USER_JAR_URL in ${JCACHE_API_URL} ${PROMETHEUS_AGENT_URL} ${BUCKET4J_CORE_URL} ${BUCKET4J_HAZELCAST_URL} ${BUCKET4J_JCACHE_URL}; do curl -sf -O -L ${USER_JAR_URL}; done
# Install
RUN echo "Downloading Hazelcast and related JARs" \
    && mkdir "${HZ_HOME}/lib" \
    && cd "${HZ_HOME}/lib" \
    && for JAR_URL in ${HAZELCAST_ALL_URL}; do curl -sf -O -L ${JAR_URL}; done \
    && echo "Granting read permission to ${HZ_HOME}" \
    && chmod 755 -R ${HZ_HOME} \
    && echo "Setting Pardot ID to 'docker'" \
    && echo 'hazelcastDownloadId=docker' > "${HZ_HOME}/hazelcast-download.properties" \
    && echo "Cleaning APK packages" \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR ${HZ_HOME}

# Start Hazelcast server
CMD ["/opt/hazelcast/start-hazelcast.sh"]
```

Comment: Your `/data/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml` file references `hazelcast-config-3.8.xsd` which isn't correct for Hazelcast 4.

Comment: I edited my config file and the problem exists yet

Answer (score 4):

Hazelcast Kubernetes discovery plugin does not allow you to specify the custom location of certificates. They are [always read](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/kubernetes/KubernetesConfig.java#L144) from the default location: `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`.

The parameter `ca-certificate` lets you inline the certificate like presented [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#outside-kubernetes-cluster), but not specify the path of the certificate.

If you think such a feature would be useful, feel to create a GH issue at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes (you can also send a PR with the change).

Comment: I don't know why, but at the beginning, before I mount the host path of the certificates, the pod couldn't find the CA, but now the error has been changed and I think it is because of my cluster role and cluster role binding. th `ca.crt` and `token` is exist in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`

Comment: Is any problem with my cluster-role and cluster-role-binding that the Hazelcast couldn't find other members?